# Extension of Scalars of Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, tensor-products

1. If we consider the complex numbers as a $\mathbb{R}$-module (vector space in this case), then its natural extension of scalars to $\mathbb{C}$ seems to be the complex numbers themselves, with the identity as embedding. But $\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{C}^2$ and this is clearly not isomorphic to $ \mathbb{C}$. I don't understand what's going on here.
2. In the spirit of the last doubt, I know that something is wrong in the following computation in $\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$, but I cannot figure out what. $$z\otimes z'= (z\otimes 1)z'=(z(1\otimes 1))z'=((1\otimes 1)z)z'=(1\otimes 1) (zz'),$$ for every complex numbers $z$ and $z'$.

---

I've realized that my mistake in 2. is in the third and fourth equalities. Translating the left action of $\mathbb{C}$ on the tensor product to the right (since the complex numbers are commutative) does not give us the same natural right action of $\mathbb{C}$ on the tensor product. But I still have that intuitive problem in 1.

Comment: In 1. you consider $\mathbb{C}$ as a 2-dimensional real vector space. When you complexify that (by tensoring with $\mathbb{C}$) you get a 2-dimensional complex vector space. Note that in general $z\otimes 1\neq 1\otimes z$. Maybe you are confusing this with $\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: My doubt is why $\mathbb{C}$ as a complex vector space wouldn't be the extension of scalars, from reals to complex numbers, of $\mathbb{C}$ as a real vector space.

Comment: @Luoisv The complex numbers are the extension *of the reals* to complex numbers. That is to say $\mathbb{R}\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @OscarCunningham. I understand what you say, but I want to know what would be the extension of the complex numbers, as a real vector space (real scalars), to a complex vector space (complex scalars). The most natural and obvious answer seems to be: the complex numbers themselves; but $\mathbb{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{C}^2$.